# GMail App showing Mobile number instead of contact name

Tags: gmail, ios

I have a contact whose emails received or sent show as a mobile number (not her real one) as the contact name in GMail on the iPhone.

I searched my contacts for that number. It existed only as a Siri-suggested 'virtual' contact. I asked Google to ignore that suggestion. I then added the number to the real contacts number, which caused my Mac and iPad to correctly show her name in the email trail. The iPhone didn't change.

I've restarted the phone, restarted the GMail app on the phone. Added and removed the number from her contact. All to no effect.

I've no idea where the number came from - it is a dead number.

Is the name of a contact in GMail app for iOS not dynamic in the way it is for computer and tablet?

Comment: Have you tried editing the contact's "File as" field in Google contacts?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: File as field is blank

Comment: How do I get GMail to show the Contact's name in email instead of this phantom mobile numer? Usually, adding/completing a field to a contact assigns it to the correct contact name. In this case, the number showing in the email list does not update in the GMail app on iPhone. It did update correctly within Mac Mail on computer, iPad. How can I upload a screenshot?